# Bash: Grep and Echo. Printing newlines between Each result

Tags: bash, grep, newline

I am trying to print the line numbers of each line with Fail in it. I am using echo `grep -n FAIL ${filename}` to print the result to the screen. However, it prints every line to teh same line. How do I breakup the result so that each line iss on it's own?

EDITED: Added input

Input would be :

FAIL

PASS

FAIL

PASSAGE

This gets a PASS

I take a pass on this

Output to the command line would be

1 FAIL

3 FAIL

Comment: why are you wrapping grep in echo?

Comment: please add example input and expected output in your question.

Comment: It's for a lab, 2)  If a file contains "FAIL(s)" then add logic to display the line number in the file that "FAIL(s)" occurred on to the screen.

Comment: Don't use `echo` on a command in backticks; that's probably causing the problem, and there are several others it can cause as well. Just run the command directly. Also, you should double-quote the variable reference. [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) is good at pointing out common mistakes like these.

Comment: See also [useless use of `echo`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo)

Answer (score 0):

This print the line number for each file with `FAIL` line

```
awk '/FAIL/ {print FNR}' file*
```

If you like file name as well

```
awk '/FAIL/ {print FNR,FILENAME}' file*
```

Or with line info

```
awk '/FAIL/ {print FNR,$0,FILENAME}' file*
```